# Python on GCE: connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Tags: python, sockets, networking, google-compute-engine, firewall

I've been working on a project that requires a bit of networking between a server (hosted on GCE) and multiple clients. I created a Compute Engine Instance to run a Python script as shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OL7fu2R4M8.

Here is my server-side script:

```
server = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) # 10.128.X.XXX which is the Internal IP
print(server)
port = 5555
clients = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((server, port))

s.listen(2)
print("Waiting for connection...")

while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: ", addr)

    conn.send(str.encode(f"{clients}"))
    clients += 1
```

and here is my client side-script:

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server = "10.128.0.2"
        self.port = 5555
        self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
        self.id = int(self.connect())

    def connect(self):
        self.client.connect(self.addr)
        return self.client.recv(2048).decode()

network = Network()
print(f"Connected as client {network.id}")
```

I know this script works because I have tested it with my computer being the server and 1 client, and another computer being the 2nd client. But when I use the GCE as the server, I get this error in the client script:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Could this be because I am using the internal IP address and not the external?

After this, I tried changing the firewall settings (added 'python-socket') of the GCE and this is what they look like:

[image]

But the error still persists...

As answered by W_B, I tried to run these commands on my VM and got the following outputs:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description it's evident it's the connection problem.

**First of all you have to check if the firewall rule you created is still there.** If it's "too broad" and allows for very wide access then it might be removed automatically even without you knowing it. It's on you'r screenshot but check it again just to be sure.

If it's there select the protocol you're goint to be using (I assume it's TCP) - [some protocols are always blocked by default](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#blockedtraffic) by GCP (you can't change this) so creating a rule with "any protocol" allowed is risky. Also - put one or two target IP's (not all inside this VPC) - this is not a must but improves security of your network.

Second - make sure port 5555 you're trying to connect to is accessible from other computers. You can scan the target host with `nmap -p 5554 put.server.ip.here`

You can scan it from the Internet or other VM's in the same VPC network.

You should get something like this:

```
root@localhost:~$ nmap -p 443 192.168.1.6
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-06-25 17:12 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.6
Host is up (0.00091s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

If you see `5555/tcp filtered freeciv` this means that something blocks the port.

Run nmap on the server (I assume you run some version of Linux) and if you don't want to install any non-essencial software you can use `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN` to get a list of open ports (5555 should be on the list).

Also make sure firewall on your server doesn't block this port. [You can use `iptables`](https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/how-to-open-ports-on-iptables-in-a-linux-server/) for that.

Comment: So I've restricted the python-socket rule to only TCP 5555 and the IP of my computer and it is apparently enabled. When I run the nmap command, it says that the 5555 port is closed. Then, if I run the netstat command, it doesn't show the 5555 port (shows just 2, tcp 0 & tcp6). I also used the iptables command to allow 5555 to be open, but the error isn't going away.

Comment: For now, I am just using my laptop as a server which is a little less convenient... but oh well. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you please paste the output of nmap & netstat commands in here ?

Comment: Yes, I will include the screenshots on the question

Comment: I also added that I am using the VM's internal IP address to connect with the socket because as soon as I try using the external one, I get this error:
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Comment: So this actually worked! I asked the question related to using the internal & external IP addresses [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631176/python-socket-to-connect-over-global-public-ip-address?] and turns out, this was the issue.

Comment: Great to hear that. If you think my answer helped you in any way I'd appreciate if you accepted it. Thanks !